# appendChild() to dynamically add images to a specific div

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I've just finished the codeacademy course on javascript so forgive my total lack of knowledge.

I'm attempting to create the classic bar game 1-4-24 (also called past midnight or after midnight) using javascript and html. (Here's a [video](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ibeninja/past-midnight-1-4-24-ios-turn-based-game-take-2-re) that shows the game for those of you who don't know what it is.

So far I've created a function that rolls the dice and stores them in an array. In a previous version of this code I was able to appendChild(img) those results in image form to the body of the page. However, I needed to be able to remove those results for when the user rolls the dice again.

I decided to use divs to separate the rolled dice, the dice the user kept and the menu used for rolling the dice.

My problem is this: I need to display the results of the die rolls in this new div. I have been very, very unsuccessful - mostly because I don't fully understand how appendChild() works even after reading multiple posts on W3schools and other sites.

So here's my code - look specifically in the addImageRolled function - I don't necessarily want it "fixed", I want to know how I can fix it. This is a learning project for me.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Put your title here</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

<script>
    // variables
    var diceLeft = 6;

    // arrays

    var rolls = [];
    var kept = [];

    // functions

    // rolls dice
    function rollDice() {
        for (var i = 0; i < diceLeft; i++) {
        rolls[i] = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        };
            displayRoll();
    };

    // creates images for displayRoll function
    function addImageRolled(id, src, width, height, hspace) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.id = id;
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.hspace = hspace;
    img.onmouseup= keepDie();
    document.getElementById("Rolled").appendChild(img);

    };

    // displays images based on rolls
    displayRoll() {
        switch(roll[0]) {
        case 1: addImageRolled(1, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 2: addImageRolled(1, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 3: addImageRolled(1, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 4: addImageRolled(1, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 5: addImageRolled(1, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 6: addImageRolled(1, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        };

        switch(roll[1]) {
        case 1: addImageRolled(2, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 2: addImageRolled(2, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 3: addImageRolled(2, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 4: addImageRolled(2, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 5: addImageRolled(2, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 6: addImageRolled(2, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        };

        switch(roll[2]) {
        case 1: addImageRolled(3, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 2: addImageRolled(3, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 3: addImageRolled(3, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 4: addImageRolled(3, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 5: addImageRolled(3, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 6: addImageRolled(3, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        };

        switch(roll[3]) {
        case 1: addImageRolled(4, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 2: addImageRolled(4, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 3: addImageRolled(4, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 4: addImageRolled(4, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 5: addImageRolled(4, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 6: addImageRolled(4, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        };

        switch(roll[4]) {
        case 1: addImageRolled(5, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 2: addImageRolled(5, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 3: addImageRolled(5, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 4: addImageRolled(5, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 5: addImageRolled(5, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 6: addImageRolled(5, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        };

        switch(roll[5]) {
        case 1: addImageRolled(6, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 2: addImageRolled(6, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 3: addImageRolled(6, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 4: addImageRolled(6, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 5: addImageRolled(6, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        case 6: addImageRolled(6, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
        break;
        };
    };

</script>

<div class="content">
    <div class="Menu">
        <div class="content">
            <p>How to play: Click "Roll!" button to roll the dice. Click on any die to keep                 it.</p>
            <input type = "button" value = "Roll!" onClick = rollDice()>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Rolled" class="Rolled">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Kept">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i try to create a fiddle, it is cribbing about a syntax error. Do you see any in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code as shown, none of which are actually related to the `.appendChild()` method - which you are using correctly.

Within your `addImageRolled()` function you have the line:

```
img.onmouseup= keepDie();
```

...but the `keepDie()` function is not defined, and also you should not have the parentheses or it calls the function immediately and assigns the result as the `onmouseup` handler. You need to actually declare the function and then use it like this:

```
img.onmouseup = keepDie;
```

Your `displayRoll()` function declaration is missing the word `function`, which gives you a syntax error. And within `displayRoll()` you reference an array called `roll` that should be `rolls`. Also this function can be made much, *much* shorter:

```
// displays images based on rolls
function displayRoll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < diceLeft; i++) {
        addImageRolled(i + 1, "dice-" + rolls[i] + ".png", 100, 100, 5);
    }
}
```

You don't need six separate switch statements that all look the same, you can just use a `for` loop to process each element of your `rolls` array. And then for any given element, `rolls[i]`, there is no need to use a switch statement to decide which image to add, because you can just concatenate the value of the `rolls[i]` element directly into the string that gives the image name.

**Here's a demo** with those changes incorporated: http://jsfiddle.net/YcwDb/3/ (Doesn't actually have images, but you can see where they would be.)

> *"I don't necessarily want it "fixed", I want to know how I can fix it. This is a learning project for me."*

Well the above should get you going. In general, if you use your browser's dev tools (displayed by pressing F12 in Chrome or IE or ctrl-shift-K in FF) these sorts of errors will be displayed in the console. Sometimes the error messages are a bit cryptic (especially for a beginner), but still they're better than wondering what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reccomend using Chrome Developer Tools (F12 in chrome) to debug the javascript. Go into "Sources", press the arrow in the top left, and find the file, then press the Roll button.

The first thing I did is add the "function" keyword before "displayRoll()" because that would throw a SyntaxError.

A few things that it showed:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: roll is not defined."

After changing all instances of "roll" to "rolls" because the array you defined is "rolls":

"Uncaught ReferenceError keepDie() is not defined."

After removing the line that references "keepDie()", as I couldn't see what it was doing, after rolling I get six images showing up on the screen.

I'd also recommend using some sort of loop for your "displayRoll()" function, to make the code cleaner and allow it to be easier to change the number of dice you want to display:

```
function displayRoll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        switch(rolls[i]) {
            case 1: addImageRolled(i+1, "dice-1.png", 100, 100, 5);
            break;
            case 2: addImageRolled(i+1, "dice-2.png", 100, 100, 5);
            break;
            case 3: addImageRolled(i+1, "dice-3.png", 100, 100, 5);
            break;
            case 4: addImageRolled(i+1, "dice-4.png", 100, 100, 5);
            break;
            case 5: addImageRolled(i+1, "dice-5.png", 100, 100, 5);
            break;
            case 6: addImageRolled(i+1, "dice-6.png", 100, 100, 5);
            break;
            };
    }
};
```

I don't believe you had any problems with "appendChild", but I'm a C# developer and my javascript knowledge is extremely minimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. onclick method 

    <input type = "button" value = "Roll!" onClick = rollDice()>

should be with wrapepd in quotes

    <input type = "button" value = "Roll!" onClick = "rollDice()">

 2. Your array is named rolls`var rolls = [];`

    but in switch you got  roll `switch(roll[0])`
```